# Error converting prototxt and caffe model from caffe to tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

I am trying to convert caffe prototxt and caffemodel file to a tensorflow and I get the following error : google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 33:3 : Expected identifier or number.

I did these steps:  LAYERS : layers , WINDOW_DATA : "INPUT" etc
I dont have caffe installed so cant upgrade_protoxt

Can anyone help me with what steps should I take , alternatively can someone convert this file in tensorflow ?http://vision.soic.indiana.edu/egohands_files/hand_classifier.prototxt